# Loop through a 2d array using angle

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, iteration, trigonometry

I am looking for method which is capable of outputting all the values in 2d array at a specified angle.. such that if I have an 2d array like this

```
 _ _ _ _ _ 
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
```

And I provided it with an angle 0 it would output values at position.(row,col) (0,3),(1,3),(2,3).

```
 _ _ _ _ _ 
|_|_|x|_|_|
|_|_|x|_|_|
|_|_|x|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
```

The problem is though, how to compute the values for 25 degrees or other angles.. I seem to be able to do it for 0,90,180,270..  but those in between i can't see it.. I must be a simple trig identity, but yeah... It sucks to be bad at math...

Comment: Really can't tell what you're asking.  45 degrees is an *odd* angle yet seems very straight forward.   For other angles (like 25 degree) we will need to know more about your homework assignment. Edit:  Sorry I mean, "problem statement" :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute-force method is to calculate the equation of the line and then use a Bresenham related algorithm to choose the slots, boxes or points that should be selected.

Think about your matrix as a screen of pixels.

Some angles (in degrees) for you to think about:  30, 60, and 22.5.

Maybe a better solution would be to constrain the angles to few in a set.  You could store the x,y positions for the few angles (such as 30 degrees).  This is based on the idea that many angles will select the same slots in the matrix.

Comment: So something like 2 one slots capable fulfill 2 angle values..  well it would make sense if the matrix were small.. but for bigger matrices this would be possible..

Comment: In your posted question, there is a limit of 5 "angles" per quadrant.  Because of your "pixel" size or slot density, no other lines can be drawn.  So a vector of 5 angles containing lists (or sub-vectors) for each coordinate.